# Local maximums of sub-tensors by index tensor

Tags: numpy, matrix, parallel-processing, pytorch, gpu

I have a tensor `x` of shape `(1,n)`, and another index tensor `d` of shape `(1,k)`. I’m trying to find the maximums of `k` sub-tensors

```
x[0:d[0]], x[d[0]:d[1]], x[d[1]:d[2]], ..., x[d[-2]: d[-1]]
```

So the output is a tensor of shape `(1,k)` with `k` local maximums. I can implement a for loop, but that’s too slow. Can I do it in parallel in PyTorch (or Numpy)?

Comment: The `torch.segment_reduce` function might be what you're looking for. I don't see any docs for it but how to use it is shown in the [unit tests](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/test/test_segment_reductions.py).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer thanks to [user7138814](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7138814/user7138814). There is a [SegmentCSR](https://pytorch-scatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/segment_csr.html) function in torch_scatter that does the job:

```
from torch_scatter import segment_csr

src = torch.randn(10, 6, 64)
indptr = torch.tensor([0, 2, 5, 6])
indptr = indptr.view(1, -1)  # Broadcasting in the first and last dim.

out = segment_csr(src, indptr, reduce="sum")

print(out.size())
torch.Size([10, 3, 64])
```

`output: torch.Size([10, 3, 64])`